# Separar un proyecto Maven en diferentes .war según servicios

Tags: java, java-ee, maven, war, microservices

**Contexto:** 
 Tengo un proyecto Maven con estructura típica, éste tiene varios WSDL para ofertar servicios construidos con CXF, el .war compilado se ejecuta sobre un Tomcat.

El proyecto oferta múltiples servicios que quiero separar para contenerizar usando Docker, la imagen base tendrá su tomcat 8 y cada contenedor ejecutará el servicio que le corresponda.

**Lo que intento:** 
 Generar cada .war por separado, intento sacar un .war por cada WSDL. Para ello llevo varios días documentándome sobre el archivo pom.xml de Maven.

**Problema:**
 No he sido capaz de descubrir como sacar un .war por cada WDSL, además todos los servicios tienen un paquete común con "útiles" y un par de archivos .xml comunes, esto hace que crear proyectos independientes sea engorroso para el mantenimiento, ya que si se cambia algo del común habría que recompilar todos los proyectos.

**Lo que intenté**

- Crear proyectos individuales y generar su .war. Evidentemente esto funciona pero perdería un mes y se vería altamente afectado el mantenimiento por las clases comunes, que al compilé en .jar para incorporarla como librería a los proyectos individuales.
- Crear estructura Java a través del wsdl para comprobar si puedo crear de forma rápida los proyectos. No  funciona correctamente debido a que algunas clases generadas (response/request) manualmente.
- Separar todo el proyecto en módulos y luego tener un módulo padre para cada servicio que se quiere ofertar, aquí el problema que me encontré es que pude compilar los módulos independientes pero no logré que el modulo padre generara un .war con los módulos hijos, algo hice mal.

**Preguntas concretas**

- ¿Puedo extraer del proyecto madre (completo) un .war por cada servicio?
- Si la respuesta anterior es afirmativa; ¿Podrías indicarme algún punto de la documentación?
- ¿Cuál es la mejor forma de modularizar micro servicios usando Maven?

Comment: No-respuesta: siempre se puede modularizar el proyecto y ponerle a cada uno su pom, que a su vez es invocado por el pom principal del proyecto.

Comment: Es lo que quise hacer en principio (lo indico en "lo que intenté") pero algo me está fallando. Seguramente sea la mejor vía y por lo que investigué (llevo 3 días pensando y buscando soluciones) parece la más adecuada. Seguramente tenga que seguir leyendo al doc sobre maven y el pom del proyecto padre. Gracias por responder.

Comment: Ojo con esto, si requieres modularizar porque quieres exponer un solo endpoint para cada war, por qué estás empaquetando en conjunto? Es decir, solo quieres exponer un endpoint pero el empaquetado va código de 10 más, eso no es modularizar. Te recomiendo separar los endpoints por proyecto.

Comment: Lo intenté y me está fallando no significa que la aproximación sea incorrecta.Significa que puede haber algo mal configurado y no lo sabemos porque no vemos nada de tu proyecto ;) Añade la info relevante a tu pregunta, detalles de los intentos y errores especificos, trazas completas de error.

Comment: Gracias, estoy creando proyectos más simples e iré creciendo para ver donde tengo el problema. De toparme con un problema concreto editaré el post.

Comment: Voto por cerrarla por el motivo: Actualmente esta pregunta incluye múltiples preguntas en una. Debería centrarse en un solo problema